Flask and CSRF tokens
I'm trying to use csrf tokens with my Flask app, but I noticed after a little bit of the site being open(1 hour), it wouldn't work unless I reloaded, so I did a little testing and found out its because of the csrf tokens expiring, so I tried generating a new one every request(which is what I want, so people can't use the same one over and over),
but it's still not working.
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template_string
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect, generate_csrf
from datetime import timedelta

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'key'
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(seconds=10)

html= """
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('redirect_route') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button type="submit">Redirect</button>
</form>
"""


@app.route('/')
def home():
    generate_csrf()
    return render_template_string(html)


@app.route('/redirect', methods=['POST'])
def redirect_route():
    generate_csrf()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


app.run(debug=True)


I have the line
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(seconds=10)
for testing, so yeah as you can see I have generate_csrf() before both routes, yet still after 10 seconds, I get the error and need to reload the site.
app.config['SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST'] = True
which didn't change anything also
session.permanent = True
didn't work also passing the new csrf token in the return statement didn't work.
So I just really don't know what to do. I want every request to have its own csrf so that it can't be used again and I don't want leaving the site open to make it not work and give an error when I press on the button it should just make a new one or something.

There is, apparently, no reason for CSRF tokens to expire (outside of a session): https://security.stackexchange.com/q/56467
in your config, set:
WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT = None

I'm less sure about 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME' but I think you're conflating user sessions with CSRF tokens, which are separate things. The CSRF token is actually embedded in the rendered page, not stored in a session

why couldnt someone just get the token from the input form by logging it in dev tools though? anyways either way, this doesnt fix the issue of when the site is left open for too long the session expires so the csrf token expires so the site wont work unless a reload is performed but i do realize i probably wasnt clear as i wasnt sure what the main problem was, so my idea was to fix it by generating a new csrf token every request so even if the session expired like the request would have a new csrf token? idrk, so either way this being in the code has the same outcome and-

im not sure about if its safe to make a session permanent or last for a long long time so that this doesnt happen, chatgpt told me i could like use js to have a ping pong message sent every 5mins so that it doesnt expire? not sure

@Caiden of course the token is exposed in the page; making it expire won't change ge that. But it doesn't matter - for it's purposes, it doesn't need to be hidden and it doesn't need to expire before the session itself
